# DbCommand does not contain a definition for ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using the following database access code which throws a compile-time error:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring  = "datasource=localhost; port=3306;username=root;password=root";

        string Query = "insert into endocrine.edata(Id,Name,Surname,Age,duration) values('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "','" + this.textBox5.Text + "');";


        MySqlConnection conDataBase  = new MySqlConnection(constring);

        MysqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MysqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        {

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
            }
            conDataBase.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
```

I am receiving the following error.

[image: error]

Comment: The error message got cut-off, could you edit your question to include the rest of it?

Comment: @Kmeixner i am new to programming, i dont even get what you are trying to tell, what i can understand right now is error is due, to non execution of ExecuteReader and non initiation of command :o

Comment: Do you have a class in your project named `MysqlCommand`? (Note lowercase 's'.)

Comment: @Vijay Raj It's ok, it looks like somebody else edited the question so that the picture of the error shows up now.

Comment: @pmcoltrane     nope, i didnt intiate any class by name MysqlCommand in project, The class which i used is (public partial class Form2 : Form)                Full code: http://codeshare.io/rs7ch

Comment: @VijayRaj the error mentions the class `mody_form.MysqlCommand`. `mody_form` is your project namespace, so there's a class named `MysqlCommand` in it somewhere. You can highlight "MysqlCommand" and hit F12 to jump to its definition. The DbCommand class provided by the MySQL library is named `MySqlCommand`, not `MysqlCommand`, and it would be in namespace `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.